# How to split a string in Python by 2 or 3, etc

Tags: python, split

Does anyone know if it's possible in python to split a string, not necessarily by a space or commas, but just by every other entry in the string? or every 3rd or 4th etc.

For example if I had "12345678" as my string, is there a way to split it into "12", "34", "56", 78"?

Comment: … and a dozen other questions, most of which have arguments about whether slicing or zipping instances of the same iterator is easier to understand/more likely to be what the OP wanted if he had an uneven-length list/faster/less typing/etc.

Comment: Darn - couldn't find that nth character one - and even then didn't think it had an re approach - oh well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
>>> x = "123456789"
>>> [x[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2)]
['12', '34', '56', '78', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension. Iterate over your string and grab every two characters using slicing and the extra options in the `range` function.

```
s = "12345678"
print([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]) # >>> ['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [the `itertools` `grouper()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which takes any arbitrary iterable and gives you groups of `n` items from that iterable:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

(Note that [in 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), this is slightly different as `zip_longest()` is called `izip_longest()`!)

E.g:

```
>>> list(grouper("12345678", 2))
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6'), ('7', '8')]
```

You can then rejoin the strings with a simple [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
>>> ["".join(group) for group in grouper("12345678", 2)]
['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

If you might have less than a complete set of values, just use `fillvalue=""`:

```
>>> ["".join(group) for group in grouper("123456789", 2, fillvalue="")]
['12', '34', '56', '78', '9']
```