# How can I split 1234 into ['12', '34'] in Python?

Tags: python

I need to split huge number into 50-digit chunks and then add it up.

Can you help me?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904086/7505436

Comment: Is the input a string? Or an `int`?

Comment: It's an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!

Answer (score -1):

```
[chunk for chunk in str(huge_number)[::50]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.